# Societies are built on PR stints and propaganda. Why are people okay with this?

Tags: society, psychology, social-norms

Every time I read, I find out that more and more 'truths', 'traditions', 'common knowledge', etc. were fabricated by some PR person in the not too distant past.  People are okay with this though, and actually defend what it means to be ______ (fill in the blank - i.e. What is means to be an American, husband, wife, Republican, etc).  Some easy examples are you must buy diamonds for marriage, bacon and eggs hearty breakfast, smoking is cool (now vaping).  I understand how we can comply and go along with it because we are not a needs-based society, we just want stuff out of boredom many times.

My question lies with the people that defend and live by certain exposed truths.  (1) What is with the defense of false things?  I love learning about truths and being true, why do people not pursue truths, be it external or internal?  I believe it makes you happier in a sense, or more grateful.  Why are people obsessed with denial?  (Perfect marriage, perfect house, perfect life, makeup, feelings, etc.)  Denial doesn't make a person happy, but they deny this fact too.  Coming clean with yourself and being true to yourself allows you to be happy.  (2) Why do people waste their life in denials?

I understand this is like a rabbit hole because this can be rooted back to the beginning of human history.  The most recent exposed truths are easy to talk about without getting into any crazy religious, philosophical debates.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Worldbuilding. Unfortunately, Stack exchange is not a discussion forum and this is basically a huge discussion question that could fill part of a library. I am also not sure how this relates to world building, because you seem to be talking about real world traditions. I am VTC because while this question could be interesting, it is not suitable for this site in its current form.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to understand what this community is about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because one persons logic isnt the same as someone else's.

Because they dont have all the information.

Because many things have conflicting information and people will choose one truth to be theirs.

Because the fear of the truth makes them choose another one.

Because the will to blame something or someone else.

Because what someone else tells you does not have to be the truth (but it could be).

Comment: And because stories are powerful, and people *want* the facts and happenings wrapped up in a neat narrative that explains and makes sense... usually want it more than they want just-facts-that-are-true